# How to unit test if a partial view compiles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Index.cshtml page I have partials views that I would like to unit test. This is the code I have for the Index.cshtml. How would I make one for a partial view?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexUnitTest()
    {
        // Arrange 
        InspectionController controller = new InspectionController();
        // Act 
        ViewResult result = controller.Index("stringHere") as ViewResult;

        // Assert 
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ViewName); 
    }
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but wanted to point out that you can force your views to be built (and fail if they fail to compile) by unloading you project, editing the `.csproj` or `vbproj` file and setting `<MvcBuildViews>` to true. Handy way to ensure your views compile before runtime.

Comment: Can't you just do a Release build? A Release build will fail if your views don't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
    public void PartialViewUnitTest()
    {
        // Arrange 
        InspectionController controller = new InspectionController();
        // Act 
        PartialViewResult result = controller.SomePartialView("stringHere") as PartialViewResult;

        // Assert 
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ViewName); 
    }
```

Try the above

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want to test, what is being returned by your partial view without moqing. But Moqing will be the right way to do this.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
      PartialViewResult response = controller.GetList(TestSearch) as PartialViewResult;


      Assert.AreEqual(response.ViewName,"_GetList");

      //Converting partial view to json string
      JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //creating serializer instance of JavaScriptSerializer class

      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      serializer.Serialize((object)response.Model, builder);

      //Checking in partial view
      Assert.IsTrue(builder.ToString().Contains("\"Success\":true"));
    }
```